# Outputting text based on 2 factors

Tags: excel, function, match

I'm currently trying to build a spreadsheet that will create a flight manifest for work. I require the manifest to output the flight number and locations based on the passengers name if it is a duplicate or if it isn't a duplicate to search another cell for a different flight.

I have attached a little snip of what I have and I'll try to explain what I require.
I need the `Flight #` cell to check if the passenger name is a duplicate. If it is it needs to output `NC786 ADL-QPT`. If it doesn't have a duplicate name then it needs to check the `origin` and if that states `PUG` then output `NC786 PUG-QPT`

edit: The Flight number "NC786 XXX-XXX" needs to change. to either "NC786 ADL-PUG", "NC786 ADL-QPT", "NC786 PUG-QPT" based on 2 factors. If the passenger name is a match then it needs to be "NC786 ADL-QPT" if it doesn't match then it needs to check the origin cell and output the flight based on that cell i.e. if the cell says "PUG" then change the flight to "NC786 PUG-QPT" or it if says "ADL" then change flight to "NC786 ADL-PUG"

***Names:***

[image]

Comment: What will it check in origin? It seems many `PUG` in `Origin` column.

Comment: I need it to check the origin from the same row as the passenger name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin field is already populated so I am not quite sure how you want to "populate" it again.  Edited, hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: The Flight number "NC786 XXX-XXX" needs to change. to either "NC786 ADL-PUG", "NC786 ADL-QPT", "NC786 PUG-QPT" based on 2 factors. If the passenger name is a match then it needs to be "NC786 ADL-QPT" if it doesn't match then it needs to check the origin cell and output the flight based on that cell i.e. if the cell says "PUG" then change the flight to "NC786 PUG-QPT" or it if says "ADL" then change flight to "NC786 ADL-PUG" This is probably how I should have explained it the first time. Apologies!!

Comment: @SamHindle  Edited, hope that helps.